# Python pandas read_csv .txt file in for loop returns none element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read from list.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
list= pd.read_csv('list.txt')
print (list)

for i in list:
    df1 = df.loc[(df['ID'] == i)]
    print ('-------------------------')
    print (df1)
```

It returns

```
  1
0  2
1  3
2  4
3  5
-------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th]
Index: []
```

Why is it returning ID column's i value as **none**, and prints Empty Dataframe?

Comment: all pandas objects have an index that gets shown in the repr. You should convert it to a list if you really want a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is returning `None` is because you are iterating over a DataFrame in a wrong way.

Have a look at this:
[pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the DataFrame values into List and then iterate through the values

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
list = df.values.tolist()

for i in range(len(list)-1):   
print(list[i])
```